# Is there a way to detect that a USB device is plugged in by detecting power draw rather than it's device driver?

Tags: windows, usb

I am building a system that needs to handle broken devices that may or may not have a working USB plug.  Would like to know if can ask USB subsystem if a port is drawing power or not.

Comment: That's an interesting question.

Comment: I'm wondering, is a more accurate question "Is there a way to detect a USB device is connected other than the driver?"?

Comment: That makes no sense.  The power source in USB has been widely ab-used.  Are you really interested in when your coffee cup is warmed up?  http://www.amazon.com/USB-Cup-Warmer-Coffee-Mug/dp/B000K1V58A  It is a bus.

Comment: @Hans - That would depend on the application.

Comment: It doesn't, it depends on what is being plugged in.

Comment: @Hans, "application" == "function being performed" or "problem being solved", in this context.

Comment: And yes, I can see this being useful as well. I've worked on (non-PC) systems that communicated with add-in cards over USB. We needed a way to learn if the device was powered, but non-responsive (we used SMBUS for that, but this could work too).

Comment: @Hans - If we're talking about a controlled environment (for instance, a research lab) vs a consumer's computer desk next to the kitchen, I think it would potentially make a difference. Notwithstanding some silly things could be plugged in, but why does the OP want to know something was plugged in (but not loaded by driver)?

Comment: Hmm, "controlled environment" is a euphemism for "our drivers suck, can't afford to make them right.  Don't mess with the cables without rebooting the machine".

Comment: @Hans, if you replace "drivers" with "hardware" (prototype, low production yield) in your comment, I'd agree with you. Regardless, I don't understand your apparent hostility towards this question.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do that you will have to dig deep:

http://www.usb.org/developers - all relevant USB standards documents
http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml - some usefull information
http://www.libusb.org/ - a library to handle USB at a very low level
http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPIspec40a.pdf - ACPI could provide some help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394504%28v=VS.85%29.aspx - WMI class to access USB related info

for a non-development solution and/or check when debugging:
http://www.devicedriverfinder.com/blog/device-drivers/how-to-check-usb-power-usage